# Ng2-smart-table bind 'Add New' button event to an external button

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, ng2-smart-table

I have been using ng2-smart-table plugin for the table grid. There is an `Add new` button to add entry into the table.

But I just want to trigger the `'Add new'` event from an external button (May be top of the table but not within the table). [There is a feature already available in the ng2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation) which is completely reverse to my requirement. That can be achieved by using `'mode:external'`.

Currently this is open with their [Github page](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/705) as an issue.

If they don't have an option with Ng2-smart-table, is there anyway to bind an event to other buttons(External) in Angular 6? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the ng2-smart-table's create event via DOM object event.

Let's say my ng2-smart-table's add button settings

```
add: {
      addButtonContent : '<span class="add"><i class=""></i></span>',
      createButtonContent:'<i class="far fa-save"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>',
      confirmCreate: true,
    }
```

then on click of your external button trigger the click of 'add' button in the ng2-smart-table like

```
onAdd(event) {
    $(".add").click();   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LocalDataSource or ServerDataSource.

I had the same question, and after trying some examples, I saw the good one [here](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/server/basic-example-load.component.ts).
In this part of the code they use the [data source method](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation) load(data) with source(LocalDataSource):

```
constructor(protected service: BasicExampleLoadService) {
   this.source = new LocalDataSource();

   this.service.getData().then((data) => {
     this.source.load(data);
   });
}
```

Then i try with my code and did the same with LocalDataSource, but to add a row into the table I did this:

```
this.source.add({
  name: 'name',
  description: 'desc',
  numQuestions: '8',
});
this.source.refresh();
```

And it work for me.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try it:
on your html:

`<button (click)="addRecord()">Add</button>
    <ng2-smart-table #smartTable [settings]="settings" [source]="source"></ng2-smart-table>`

on your component:

    `@ViewChild('smartTable') smartTable;
    .
    .
    .
    addRecord() {
        this.smartTable.grid.createFormShown = true;
        this.smartTable.grid.getNewRow();
    }`